# Сохранение пользователя, Spring Security, ROLE

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Рассматриваю сейчас пример "Регистрация, вход через спринг" https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-xml-configuration-maven-jsp-and-mysql/

При регистрации нового пользователя, после нажатия кнопки Submit, срабатывает метод, который берет в базе ВСЕ существующие ROLE (сейчас у меня созданы ROLE_USER и ROLE_ADMIN) и добавляет их пользователю автоматически.[image: java security]

Вопрос:
Не могу понять, как отправить в метод только ROLE_USER, что бы автоматически пользователь создавался именно с ним, а ROLE_ADMIN, добавлялся вручную.

Вот гит пример:
https://github.com/hellokoding/registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql

Вот метод, который отвечает за сохранение нового пользователя.
https://github.com/hellokoding/registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hellokoding/account/service/UserServiceImpl.java#L24

Пытался, вытащить со списка первое значение, через `new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll())` и `get(0)`, но не получилось, он требует что бы мы ему дали тип данных "Role", а я что-то не сильно могу понять, как должен выглядеть код.

Буду благодарен, за любую подсказку. Спасибо.

Comment: Ищите роль юзера по ИД и назначаете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подозреваю, что вы могли в конструктор HashSet передавать Role, а не их коллекцию. Должно быть как-то так:

```
    Role roleUser = roleRepository.findOne(1L); // если ROLE_USER гарантирована с id=1
    // Role roleUser = roleRepository.findOneByName("ROLE_USER"); // альтернативный вариант
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>(); // т.к. User.setRoles требует Set
    roles.add(roleUser); // создадим Set с одним значением
    user.setRoles(roles);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш код подошел. Так же увидел проблему, помогла Ваша фраза с "// т.к. User.setRoles требует Set", тестировал на кануне и влепил туда HashSet, и пытался, с хэшсета вытащить первое значение. Не подскажете, почему не получилось у меня так сделать?

Comment: Подскажите,  `roleRepository.findAll()` находил все значения.   `new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll())` - все что нашли запихивается в коллекцию HashSet.   `User.setRoles требует Set` - но ранее туда спокойно влазил и HashSet, как так?

Comment: Set -- интерфейс, HashSet реализует интерфейс Set